# Why does URLLoader.bytesTotal return a different value if the file is online or local?

Tags: xml, file, actionscript-3, air, local-storage

I've got an xml file in my AIR app and I'm trying to determine his size. Here's what I did :

```
 var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("horaires3.xml");
    trace(file.url); //path to the file
    trace(file.size);
```

But I've got this error : `Error #3003: File or directory does not exist.`

The `file.url` is working, but the `file.size` is throwing the error..

Apparently, I have to use `FileReference` instead of File but I don't really understand in what way it's changing my code.

**EDIT :**

Here's what I did (seems more complex so I don't know if it's the good way to do it) :

```
function checking_version_of_horairesXML():void{

    var url_local:URLRequest = new URLRequest("horaires3.xml");
    var url_online:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mywebsite.nc/horaires3.xml");


// Define the URLLoader.
var loader_local:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader_local.load(url_local);

var loader_online:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader_online.load(url_online);

// Listen for when the file has finished loadingloader_local_Complete
loader_local.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_local_Complete);
loader_online.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_online_Complete);


function loader_local_Complete(e:Event):void {

     trace("size of local file : " + (URLLoader(e.target).bytesTotal)); 
}

function loader_online_Complete(e:Event):void
{

     trace("size of online file : " + (URLLoader(e.target).bytesTotal));

}
```

It seems that the code for the local file is working as I'm getting in output :

```
size of local file: 703693
```

But I've uploaded the exact same file on my server and I have this in output :

```
size of online file : 60243
```

Why am I getting different results as these 2 files are identical ?

Comment: It could be server-side compression. I've encountered issues with SWFs not loading correctly on a server because of this.